# How to install pip in python 3.8 (through Spyder)?

Tags: python, pip, spyder

I am trying to install pip in spyder, running python version 3.8.

I have saved the file from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and set my working directory to the folder that the file is in.

I run `python3 get-pip.py`  but it gives me the following error: invalid syntax

I also tried `ipython get-pip.py`, `python get-pip.py`, `ipython3 get-pip.py`, but all of them are incorrect syntaxes.
I have checked if pip was not installed already and it says 'No module named pip'

Could anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: can you share full error message after running `python3 get-pip.py` ?

Comment: `` python3 get-pip.py
  Cell In[31], line 1
    python3 get-pip.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ``

Comment: run this command in terminal not on ipython

Comment: Here i get the following error: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store,
 or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: just check your interpreter in your syder or in your system. if python is not install install it from official website and by default pip come with python now a days

Comment: Just downloaded it but i cannot seem to open it in the terminal, it says python3: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\Celin\\get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file 
or directory

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-python-windows-10 follow this and then in spyder add the python path  of installed python

Comment: I followed the link you mentioned and added the path in spyder within the PYTHONPATH manager. Unfortunately i still cannot use pip ..

Answer (score 0):

try running:

`conda install pip`

Comment: then it gives me back this Cell In[30], line 1
    get_ipython().run_line_magic('conda', 'install pip')

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2364 in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:87 in conda
    raise ValueError("The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  "

ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use ``%pip install`` instead.

Comment: okay, try and install python3-pip with the package manager you have, ie ````apt install python3-pip```` if it's a debian distro, ````yum install python3-pip```` if it's red hat etc.

Comment: Both give back: 'incorrect syntax'

Comment: do you know what your package manager or distro is - linux/windows/macOS etc

Comment: I have a windows computer, im not sure what a package manager/distro means

Comment: okay, have you ran the following from the terminal:
````curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py````
if not, try it, then try rerunning your get-pip commands

Comment: Invalid syntax again .. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251723/discussion-between-jacob-kearney-and-celine-serry).